# How Can I Query for Unique Value and Update another Field in Same Table If return True mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update mysql table pin if Pin field value is the same as the user input pin.In this case, I want to update appid field in the pin table once the the select query returns true.

```
<?php 
If(isset($_POST['login'])){
$Pin=$_GET['pin'];
$ID =$_POST['ID'];
if($Pin!=''){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pin WHERE Pin  = '$Pin'");
$test = mysql_fetch_array($result);

mysql_query("UPDATE pin SET appid ='$num' WHERE Pin= '$Pin'")
            or die(mysql_error()); 

header("location:compet_applicant.php");
}
}
              
?>
```

Comment: Well, what's the problem, any errors, ... ?

Comment: Add another column that identifies a row has been edited already or not.

Comment: You can use `lastInsertId();`

Comment: `$num` is undefine in your code!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add one more `field` like: `number_update` into your `pin` table first. Default value is `0`
First time update, it will have value is `1` and you could check that value,
if it is `1`, will alert `ID Already in Use, Pls login`. If it is `0`, allow to update

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pin WHERE Pin  = '$Pin'");
$test = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $test[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
}

if($test["number_update"] == 1) { //Checking already updated
    //Notify user that they have already updated
} else {
    mysql_query("UPDATE pin SET appid ='$num' WHERE Pin= '$Pin'")
        or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Show in my code sample where to place ur suggestion for easy understanding

Comment: this is the best solution for checking updatation @Mr Neo. but why you ask show in my code #lgbeh...it is not free coding writing services...try your self if any problem then ask...

Comment: @Mak, I have done my best and even pasted my working codes. Moreover, this is a place to learn from one another and not a place to insult or look down on another so please if u don't have anytin to offer then leave others to give their inputs, pls

Comment: @Mak, I have done my best and even pasted my working codes. Moreover, this is a place to learn from one another and not a place to insult or look down on another so please if u don't have anytin to offer then leave others to give their inputs, pls

Comment: i think you enjoy ready made code not learn. Mr Neo give solution with explanation but you want code so it is not a learning effort..and now you justify your self..@lgbeh Emmanuel

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $Pin = $_GET['pin'];
    $ID  = $_POST['ID'];
    if ($Pin != '') {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pin WHERE Pin  = '$Pin'");
        $test   = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $test[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
        }

        if ($test["number_update"] == 1) { //Checking already updated
            //Notify user that they have already updated
        } else {
            mysql_query("UPDATE pin SET appid ='$num',number_update = 1 WHERE Pin= '$Pin'") or die(mysql_error());
        }

        header("location:compet_applicant.php");
    }
}
?>
```

Add one more field "number_update" in your database table as suggested by Mr. Neo and replace your code with the above code.

Comment: I have done every thing right as you have shown but the script is still updating the table even as the number_update field is been updated to 1 as again the default 0 value

Comment: @MrNeo, how should i check? `$test["number_update"]` is 1 in table

Comment: you could write log or `alert` `$test["number_update"]` to check it's value

Comment: @lgbeh  'number_update'  this column wasn't set to 1 on update in earlier solution.Solution has been updated now.Please try this.If worked,please accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a log table that record each updation of tables. If the record found then system should prevent further updation for that particular record.

```
    <?php 
    If(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $Pin=$_GET['pin'];
    $ID =$_POST['ID'];
    if($Pin!=''){
    $update_count = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Audit_Table_Update WHERE Field_name  = 'Pin' and field_value='$pin');

if(!mysql_num_rows($update_count)){

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pin WHERE Pin  = '$Pin'");
    $test = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    mysql_query("UPDATE pin SET appid ='$num' WHERE Pin= '$Pin'")
                or die(mysql_error()); 

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO AUDIT_TABLE_UPDATES (TABLE_NAME, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_VALUE,TIME_UPDATED) VALUES('Pin','appid',$num,systemtime)")
                or die(mysql_error()); 

    header("location:compet_applicant.php");
    } // end if update count
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: @Mhammad Muazzam, So where is the code checking for duplicate entry and alerting users that the pin or ID is already in use?

Comment: I have provided in hints. You can write down code yourself.

Comment: `<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pin WHERE Pin  = '$Pin'");
$test = mysql_fetch_array($result);

mysql_query("UPDATE pin SET appid ='$num' WHERE Pin= '$Pin'")
            or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO pinlog (TableName,pin,id,TIME_UPDATED) VALUES('Pin','$Pin','$num','$date')")
            or die(mysql_error()); 

header("location:compet_applicant.php");
}
}

?> `

Comment: Put the count and add if condition where suggested